# Remove parent anchor element if span has only # in it

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove all anchor element where nested `<span></span>` tag has only `#` in it example

**Remove This one**

```
<a  href="/search.aspx?search=something" class="keyword"><span class="tags">#</span></a>
```

**Don't remove this one has some text with #**

```
<a  href="/search.aspx?search=something" class="keyword"><span class="tags">#Sometext</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter to return the spans which has only `#` text in it. Then find the parent anchor either by `closest("a")` or `parent()`

```
$("span.tags").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == "#"
}).closest("a").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function,

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.text) === '#';
}).remove();
```

Or

```
$('a').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($('span.tags',this).text()) === "#";
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".keyword").filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == "#" ? true : false;
}).remove();
```

Demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/663/

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if there is one or more than one .tags span, it should work

```
<script>
$(function(){  
    $('.tags').each(function(){
        if( $(this).text() == "#" ){
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```